# Redux: one huge action or several small actions?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

**Question**

I have doubts, what is correct - emit several small actions (every action would be responsible for the particular part of the state) or dispatch one huge action that would handle all parts of the state by one change?

**Use case**

I have action - `InitializeModule`. When I dispatch it, I catch it in effects, do several requests - for example, `getGoods()`, `getOrders()`, `getPopularPositions()` and then want to fulfill the state by these responses. We can map it in effect as:

`return [new SetGoods(goods), new SetOrders(orders), new SetPopularPositions(positions)]`

or we can do something like

`return new SetInitialData({goods, orders, positions})`.

So, first option will trigger reducer three times, but it would be pretty explicit. And, second option is about not so explicit action (`SetInitialData` - pretty obvious, but still it does more changes in several places) but trigger store change only once.
What is correct way?

@ngrx/store + effects are used

Comment: multiple small actions are always better because its easier debug problems in them.